# XMLHttpRequest is not working on react native app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest api for requesting resources from server in react native android app 
Here is my app code (client side)

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text,View,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
class Home extends Component
{
  state={con:''}

show=()=>
{
    alert("show function called");
    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange=(e)=>
    {
        if(req.status==200 && req.readyState==4)
        {
            alert(req.responseText);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/show_react");
    req.send();
}

render()
{
    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.show()} style={styles.box}><Text>Click</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    <Text>{this.state.con}</Text>
    </View>
    );
}
}  
  export default Home;

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
box:
{
    padding:10,
    width:200,
    marginTop:10,
    backgroundColor:'rgba(215, 44, 149, 0.7)',
    alignItems:'center'
},
container:
{
    flexDirection:'row',
    justifyContent:'center'
}
});
```

And below is my simple node.js code (Server side) for accepting request from the client

```
app.get("/show_react",function(req,res){
console.log("show_react called");
res.send("hii react");
});
```

The above server side code runs successfully when it is requested by the browser but it doesn't works when requested by the client (react native app).
Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `fetch`? It's a much more friendly API that's *supported* in React Native.

Comment: But XMLHttpRequest api is much easier to learn. All of the syntax is similar to pure javascript XMLHttp request

Comment: `fetch` is a part a Web API just like XMLHttpRequest and *is JavaScript*, I don't understand your statement about "syntax similar to pure javascript". `fetch` itself also has more capabilities and **is supported by React Native**, unlike XMLHttpRequest. And IMO it's not easier to learn. Instead of your 8-10 lines of code with XMLHttpRequest, you can do it in 3 lines with `fetch`.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is supported by React Native. Your code does not seem to have issues, could you elaborate on how it does not work, what do you receive, any errors etc?

Also, could you check with another server, just to make sure that issue is about XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Okay... In client side i have just created a button. When the button is touched , show function is called. This show function will create a new XMLHttpRequest (http://localhost:3000/show_react) to the localhost server running at port 3000.

Comment: Now client recieves the request and "Hi react" is printed on the node.js server console. But my server doesn't recieve any request from the client. The above url works good when it is requested by the browser.

Comment: In that case, this is not a problem about XMLHttpRequest. Which headers does your server expect? For example, if your server expects to get HTTP Accept headers and you are providing none, does it respond with the default response or does it not respond at all?

Answer (score 3):

> Okay... In client side i have just created a button. When the button is touched , show function is called. This show function will create a new XMLHttpRequest (localhost:3000/show_react) to the localhost server running at port 3000.

If your request URL in the react native application is really `localhost:3000/show_react` then your problem is that `localhost` points to your local device (i.e. smartphone). The URL needs to be accessible from the device where you run your react native application. Try to browse to the URL in the Safari browser on your device (i.e. smartphone)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Fetch, you must use a drop in React-Native replacement for Fetch; Fetch's API in react-native is a wrapper around XMLHttpRequest.
I use react-native-blob-util as it uses NativeModules to implement fetch.

I did work tracking down why my XMLHttpRequest is broken for me and I did not find out why. I did find that instead of something like xhr.onload, I could do xhr.addEventListener('load', ()...) it would work. May be helpful for future seekers